# Call a webservice asmx soap request from Xamarin C#

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, xamarin

I am trying to call a webservice.asmx method, I can only use the soap request because the get/post is disabled by default where this service has deployed. I am using this code and trying the service code in local machine for now to test my calling code:
Service code:

```
 [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
     [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class FullNameWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        Logging logging = new Logging();

        [WebMethod]
        public string FullName(string firstName,string lastName)
        {
            return firstName+" "+lastName;
        }
    }
```

Calling code:

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program n = new Program();
            n.GetFullName();
        }
        public async Task<int> GetFullName()
        {
            try
            {
                var soapString = this.ConstructSoapRequest();
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SOAPAction", "http://localhost:50370/FullNameWebService.asmx/GetFullName");
                    var content = new StringContent(soapString, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
                    var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:50370/FullNameWebService.asmx/GetFullName", content);
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }

        }

        private string ConstructSoapRequest()
        {
            return String.Format(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
            <s:Envelope xmlns:s=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
                <s:Body>
                    <GetFullName xmlns=""http://localhost:50370/FullNameWebService.asmx/"">
                        <firstName>ABC</firstName>
                        <lastName>ccompany</lastName>
                    </GetFullName>
                </s:Body>
            </s:Envelope>");
        }
    }
```

At response my code stops, I run the service in debug mode and then run calling application but it is not reaching to service

Comment: first, you need to use an IP address or FQDN instead of localhost

Comment: It did'nt work.